# Understanding the steps to say that the condition number is $ \kappa(A) = \left\Vert A^{-1} \right\Vert \cdot \left\Vert A \right\Vert$

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, error-propagation, condition-number

I was reading the [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) regarding the *condition number*, and it states:

> For example, the condition number associated with the linear equation $Ax = b$ gives a bound on how inaccurate the solution $x$ will be after approximation.
>
> ...
>
> In particular, one should think of the condition number as being (very roughly) the rate at which the solution, $x$, will change with respect to a change in $b$. Thus, if the condition number is large, even a small error in $b$ may cause a large error in $x$. On the other hand, if the condition number is small then the error in $x$ will not be much bigger than the error in $b$.

This is quite understandable, but then we have the following steps.

> The condition number is defined more precisely to be the *maximum ratio of the relative error in $x$ divided by the relative error in $b$*.
>
> Let $e$ be the error in $b$. Assuming that $A$ is a nonsingular matrix, the error in the solution$A^{−1}b$ is $A^{−1}e$. The ratio of the relative error in the solution to the relative error in b is
>
> $${\displaystyle {\frac {\frac {\left\Vert A^{-1}e\right\Vert }{\left\Vert A^{-1}b\right\Vert }}{\frac {\left\Vert e\right\Vert }{\left\Vert b\right\Vert }}}} $$

The description seems to match up *partially* with the formula, because the description is talking about a *maximum* and I don't see it described in the formula. I've also a doubt regarding what the author means by "the error in b" or "the error in x". What error are we talking about, and why?

Then, this formula/fraction is manipulated to obtain:

> $${\displaystyle \left({\frac {\left\Vert A^{-1}e\right\Vert }{\left\Vert e\right\Vert }}\right)\cdot \left({\frac {\left\Vert b\right\Vert }{\left\Vert A^{-1}b\right\Vert }}\right)}$$

This was just simple algebraic manipulation. But then it says:

> The maximum value (for nonzero $b$ and $e$) is easily seen[clarification needed] to be the product of the two operator norms:
>
> $${\displaystyle \kappa (A)=\left\Vert A^{-1}\right\Vert \cdot \left\Vert A\right\Vert}$$

I don't see any connection why the previous statement should be true, *with respect to its previous statements*. Can you please explain me how the author(s) made this last conclusion? Which steps did he do to reach this point of saying that the condition number of a matrix is defined as $${\displaystyle \kappa (A)=\left\Vert A^{-1}\right\Vert \cdot \left\Vert A\right\Vert}$$

*Note: if someone wants then to edit the Wikipedia's article by writing his/her explanation also there, it would be nice, since someone asked also for explanation there.*

Comment: In regards to your first question, 'the descriptions is talking about a maximum and I don't see one'. The [definition of a matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm) is that $$\| A \| = \text{sup} \left \{ \frac{\| Ax \|}{\| x \|}, \| x \| \ne 0 \right \}$$ i.e a maximum. In regards to your second question 'I don't see any connection why the previous statement should be true', this again just uses the definition of a matrix norm and the fact that $$\frac{1}{\| A^{-1} \|} \le \| A \|$$

Answer (score 1):

The expression
$$
\left({\frac {\left\Vert A^{-1}e\right\Vert }{\left\Vert e\right\Vert }}\right)\cdot \left({\frac {\left\Vert b\right\Vert }{\left\Vert A^{-1}b\right\Vert }}\right)
$$
is the ratio of the relative error in $x$ divided by the relative error in $b$, for a fixed choice of $b$ and $e$.  What we want is the *maximum* that this value can attain.  In particular, we want to find
$$
\max_{e,b \neq 0}
\left({\frac {\left\Vert A^{-1}e\right\Vert }{\left\Vert e\right\Vert }}\right)\cdot \left({\frac {\left\Vert b\right\Vert }{\left\Vert A^{-1}b\right\Vert }}\right) = 
\left(\max_{e \neq 0} {\frac {\left\Vert A^{-1}e\right\Vert }{\left\Vert e\right\Vert }}\right)\cdot \left(\max_{b \neq 0}{\frac {\left\Vert b\right\Vert }{\left\Vert A^{-1}b\right\Vert }}\right) = \\
\left(\max_{e \neq 0} {\frac {\left\Vert A^{-1}e\right\Vert }{\left\Vert e\right\Vert }}\right)\cdot \left(\max_{x \neq 0}{\frac {\left\Vert Ax\right\Vert }{\left\Vert x\right\Vert }}\right)
$$
Now, by the [definition of an operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm#Equivalent_definitions), this is the product $\|A^{-1}\| \cdot \|A\|$, as desired.